Ansible: become from a passwordless user
I have a user with no password, and want Ansible to use sudo from that user, without adding NOPASSWD to the sudoers file. Ansible complains with: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}
In more detail: There are two users, my_user and root. root is password-protected. my_user has no password and is accessed via private SSH key. The sudoers file contains %sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL. Manually attempting to use sudo from my_user works without getting any password prompt.
Playbook:
- name: VM deployment
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
    - name: "Add the VM as an ansible host"
      ansible.builtin.add_host:
        name: '{{ my_ip }}'
        groups:
          - my_vm
        ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
        ansible_user: 'my_user'

- name: "VM configuration"
  hosts: my_vm
  gather_facts: false
    - name: Install some packages
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        deb: "/tmp/somepackage.deb"
      become: true  # FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}
      become_method: sudo

From existing questions, I've found that changing the sudoers line to %sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL fixes the problem. I would prefer not to do this because it should not be necessary for this user (which already has no password):
    # This works
    - name: Install some packages
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: 'sudo apt-get install -y /tmp/somepackage.deb'

Is there a nice way to get this working without editing /etc/sudoers?

What's the problem with using NOPASSWD? the effect is the same, your root user is compromised already by allowing a user without password to do sudo.

It is possible to configure sudo to require a different password than the user password: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158416/how-to-allow-authentication-with-sudo-using-an-alternate-password

@GeraldSchneider I am spawning the VMs from a premade debian11 template. I will change the file if that's how it has to be, but it seems like an unnecessarily roundabout method when all I'm trying to do is get Ansible to call sudo normally.

try to run with -K and supply empty password, or supply it via become_pass: "" in the playbook

@NikitaKipriyanov as far as I can tell, Ansible only uses these values for the root password (which is not empty). But yeah, that's basically what I'm looking for, a way to tell Ansible "my user password is empty, please use that"

No, it is used as it is called: a password for whatever become method you are using. If you using su, it's being used as a root password. If sudo, it's being used as a user password. For instance, I have non-empty-passworded user, and configured sudo become method, and I run ansible-playbook -K and enter my password to become. root definitely has another password on my managed machines, not the one I am entering.
